# Aggregate the result from two files using Python Spark code using joins

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, hdfs

Hello Everyone I am new to python and spark so i need help from you all.
i have two files and i loaded them using SparkContext

```
file1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/out1/part-00000")
file2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/out2/part-00000")
```

File1 contain following data.

```
c_id   date         TM        cn_id      c_val  tc
10201   2015-4-15  00:00:00  56707065  0         0
10201   2015-4-15  00:00:00  56707066  1         0
10201   2015-4-15  00:00:00  56707067  200       0
```

like wise there are multiple c_id and for each c_id the cn_id is different and the c_value is different in file 1 tc is fixed i.e 0.

File2 contain following data.

```
c_id   dt          tm        cn_id      c_val  tc
10201   2015-4-15  01:00:00  56707065  300      1
10201   2015-4-15  01:00:00  56707066  60        1
10201   2015-4-15  01:00:00  56707067  20        1
```

here tc is fixed i.e. 1

All the values are same in the file one and file two only the c_val changes as per the cn_id so I want the third file which contains the sum of c_val i.e for `c_id 10201` & for the `cn_id 56707065` i want the result like this `10201   2015-4-15  01:00:00  56707065  0+300 =300`  so finally the output in third file will be,

```
10201   2015-4-15  01:00:00  56707065 300 1
```

similarly for `cn_id 56707066,56707067` aggregate the result and put it into third file. please suggest me the python spark snippet.

i want this result using join in python spark or if any other technic in spark using pyhton.

Comment: You should try to code and if you are struck people provide solution.

Comment: Please, post your attempts so far and explain what kind of problems you experience. It is close to trivial task with either `file1.union.file.map(split_and_cast_cval).reduceByKey(add)` or Spark DataFrames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you could join on cn_id and then add up c_val

You have 2 easy approach, one is to zip each file with Index (in scala-spark, I use zipWithIndex, and union the result, groupBy zipped id, and reduce by adding the c_val column.

Your second solution is zip and add (which reserves the index automatically) in scala my code looks something like:

```
(filea,fileb).zipped.map((x,y)=> ((x.c_val+y.c_val)))
```

solution 3, it seems your cn_id can also be used to index the correct pairs. you can do:
    filea.union(fileb).groupBy(_.cn_id) and reduce c_val by add

Answer (score 0):

I have combined two files and made separate ones.  It contains some float c_val also, I have the following code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Aggregate")
file1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/parse/combine/joined.txt")
file2 = file1.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(','))\
             .map(lambda x: (x[0] + ',' + x[3], float(x[4])))\
             .reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).coalesce(1)

final_agg = file2.map(lambda x: (x[0]+','+ x[3], float(x[4])))\
                 .reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)\
                 .coalesce(1)
print(file2.collect())
```

I am getting the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

As per the above code, the expected output is:

```
[( '10201,56707065',300), ('10201,56707066',61)]
```

and the input file contains data like:

```
10201,  '2015-4-15',  '00:00:00',  56707065,    '0',    0
10201   '2015-4-15',  '00:00:00',  56707066,    '1',    0
10201   '2015-4-15',  '00:00:00',  56707067,    '200',  0
10201,  '2015-4-15',  '00:30:00',  56707065,    '300',  1
10201   '2015-4-15',  '00:30:00',  56707066,     '60',  1
10201   '2015-4-15',  '00:30:00',  56707067,     '20',  1
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.